# How to load PHPMailer on cakePHP 3

Tags: composer-php, phpmailer, cakephp-3.0

After googling a lot and trying many things I couldn't load PHPMailer on cakePHP 3.

I did the installation using compose and all files are on vendor folder, but I get always a error on this line:

```
$mail = new PHPMailer();
```

Should I include in the composer.json autoload some reference to PHPMailer?

```
 "autoload": {
    "psr-4": {
        "App\\": "src"         
    }
},
```

Thank you

Comment: And that mysterious error is (when receiving errors, please always include the exact error message in your question)? Let me guess, something like "_class \App\Foo\Bar\PHPMailer not found..._"?

Comment: yes, you are right @ndm. This is the error: Error: Class 'App\Controller\PHPMailer' not found. Any idea how to point to Vendor\phpmailer\phpmailer\. Thank you

Comment: You are missing a leading namespace separator in order to access the global namespace where the `PHPMailer` class lives, ie `new \PHPMailer()`. This is kindof a duplicate.

Comment: Thanks @ndm this was the right solution!!!    $mail = new \PHPMailer();
you give me the final solution for a problem that I'm trying to solve during last two weeks.